# How can I calculate prices based on currency table in one select?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table of invoices that can be in multiple currencies that looks like this:

```
| id | issue_date | total | currency |
|----|------------|-------|----------|
| 1  | 2020-04-20 | 1234  | EUR      |
| 2  | 2020-04-26 | 2345  | USD      |
| 1  | 2020-04-27 | 9876  | EUR      |
| 3  | 2020-04-28 | 3456  | RON      |
```

And i have a currency table that holds currency exchange rates that looks like this:

```
| id | date       | currency_id | rate    |
|----|------------|-------------|---------|
| 1  | 2020-04-20 | EUR         | 1       |
| 2  | 2020-04-20 | USD         | 1.08600 |
| 3  | 2020-04-20 | RON         | 4.83560 |
```

What I would like to achieve is to calculate each invoice price based on its `issue_date`, `currency` and a target currency.

All currency exchange rates are based on EUR so its value will always be 1. Currencies are updated daily but there are dates missing (during weekend exchange rates don't update) so calculation needs to be based on most recent exchange rate until `invoice.issue_date`

So what I tried was this:

```
SELECT
    `i`.`id`,
    `i`.`total`,
    `i`.`currency`,
    `exr1`.`rate` as `invoice_rate`,
    `exr2`.`rate` AS `target_rate`,
    `i`.`total` * `exr1`.`rate` as `euro_price`,
    `i`.`total` * `exr1`.`rate` / `exr2`.`rate` AS `target_price`
FROM `invoices` as `i`

LEFT JOIN `exchange_rates` AS `exr1`
ON
    `exr1`.`currency_id` = `i`.`currency` AND
    `exr1`.`date` = `i`.`issue_date`

LEFT JOIN `exchange_rates` as `exr2`
ON
    `exr2`.`currency_id` = 'RON' AND
    `exr2`.`date` = `i`.`issue_date`

GROUP BY
    `i`.`id`,
    `invoice_rate`,
    `target_rate`

ORDER BY `i`.`issue_date` DESC
```

#### Problem nr. 1

Because there are no exhange rates for the exact invoice dates I get `null` values. I tried changing the LEFT JOIN ON to something like `exr1.date <= i.issue_date` but GROUP BY invoice doesn't work anymore (i get duplicates).

#### Problem nr. 2

For rows that have exchange rates on that exact day I get wrong values because based on the target currency I need to either multiply or divide:
`i.total * exr1.rate * exr2.rate AS usd_price` vs `i.total * exr1.rate / exr2.rate AS usd_price`

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e5GnVnry5sAiXwbuScV6JT/19

Answer (score 1):

This is a (rare) case where a dependent subquery is the way to go. Here's the overall query  (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e5GnVnry5sAiXwbuScV6JT/21)

```
SELECT id, 
       total,
       currency,
       rate,
       total / rate euro_price
  FROM (  SELECT i.id,
                 i.total,
                 i.currency,
                 (SELECT e.rate
                    FROM exchange_rates e
                   WHERE e.currency_id = i.currency
                     AND e.date <= i.issue_date
                   ORDER BY e.date DESC
                   LIMIT 1) rate
              FROM invoices i
        ) d
```

The dependent subquery is this:

```
                  SELECT e.rate
                    FROM exchange_rates e
                   WHERE e.currency_id = i.currency
                     AND e.date <= i.issue_date
                   ORDER BY e.date DESC
                   LIMIT 1
```

It finds the exchange rate for the most recent date equal to or before the `issue_date`. It's called *dependent* because it refers to column values in its outer query.

This isn't going to be fast. A covering index on `exchange_rates(currency_id, date DESC, rate)` will help. Like this.

```
CREATE INDEX lookup ON exchange_rates(currency_id, date DESC, rate);
```

I used a nested query so the outer query can simply refer to `rate` as a column when it needs to, rather than repeating the dependent subquery.

Also note I think you want to divide, not multiply, when computing your euro_price.

I left the second rate lookup to you.

**Pro tip*  Only use the backtick marks when your table or column name is a reserved word in the query language. Your queries are MUCH easier to read without them.

Comment: This indeed works but it's painfully slow: about 15 seconds for 272 invoices even with the index. The currency exchange rate table has entries since 1990. So I need some out of the box ideas to make it work in a production setup.What if I populate the missing dates with the previous days so I don't have gaps in the data?

Comment: @Angelin have you found the solution?

Comment: Yes, filling missing gaps with previous day worked like a charm